# CakePHP: is it possible to access a protected function from controller?

Tags: php, cakephp

I wrote two actions in a controller `some_controller` that allow a person to download a file. The procedure goes like this:

1. User goes to `some_controller/export_data` and clicks on a form to generate a text file.
2. The action `export_data()` then writes a text file for the user.
3. Once it is detected that a file has been generated, another button appears for the user to click to download the file via the Media View. This action is `some_controller/download_file`.

My question is, how do I make `some_controller/download_file` inaccessible by the user manually? i.e. I want to prevent the user from typing this URL into the browser and download the file. I tried setting `protected function _download_file()`, but this makes the view unable to access the action in `some_controller`.

I feel like I'm approaching this the wrong way. Anybody want to give me some directions?

Comment: maybe try `private` instead of `protected`? Let me know if that works..

Comment: Looks to me like privates cannot be accessible through the request. But it's very late and I'm crossing eyes... https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php#L466-L497

Comment: I tried `private` earlier, but then the view wouldn't even recognize the action exists. `protected` gave me an access denied error. The DB I need to use at work is currently offline, so I'm gonna have to try it again on Monday. I will update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When user click `generate a text file` button:

1. In `some_controller/export_data` action set a session variable
2. In `some_controller/download_file` action check that session variable first.
3. If it is set, then allow user to download the file and destroy the session.
4. And if it is not then do now allow him to download file.

In this way, you can assign `some_controller/download_file` `public` access.

if a user directly access `some_controller/download_file action`, then session variable will not be there and he cannot download the file.

Comment: This seems to works just great. I will take note of the session variable for other purposes! Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible for me to check whether the file (generated by Model View in `download_file`) has been actually downloaded by user?

Answer (score 1):

The action cannot be protected because you need it when the user clicks the download button.  The best you can do is guard it which is perfectly acceptable.  For example you could do the following:

1. In export_data generate a random key (i.e. 1234) that represents the file
2. When the button appears, the url contains the key that represents the file (i.e. ../some_controller/download_file?key=1234)
3. In download_file, check that key both exists and represents a file that is ready for download.  If the key is good give them the file, if it isn't show an error message.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I ended up going with the session variable, which in principle is very similar to your suggestion. Thanks!